How to avoid "Divide by zero error encountered."
Upon executing the SQL code provided, an error message is displayed stating

Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Line 27 Divide by zero error encountered.

SELECT 'Accounts.Payment_Frequency__c' AS Table_ColumnName,
   'Payment Frequency' AS [DATA ELEMENT],
   COUNT(*) as Total_cnt, 
   COUNT(Payment_Frequency__c) as TotalNotNull,
   COUNT(*) - COUNT(Payment_Frequency__c) AS TotalNull,
   CONCAT(100 * (COUNT(*) - COUNT(Payment_Frequency__c))/COUNT(*),'%') AS [Percent]
FROM [EDLCleansed].[SF].[Accounts]

Nevertheless, employing NULLIF would result in the following error:

Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 27 Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '%' to data type int.

SELECT 'Accounts.Payment_Frequency__c' AS Table_ColumnName,
   'Payment Frequency' AS [DATA ELEMENT],
   COUNT(*) as Total_cnt, 
   COUNT(Payment_Frequency__c) as TotalNotNull,
   COUNT(*) - COUNT(Payment_Frequency__c) AS TotalNull,
   CONCAT(100 * (COUNT(*) - COUNT(Payment_Frequency__c))/NULLIF(COUNT(*),'%'),0) AS [Percent]
FROM [EDLCleansed].[SF].[Accounts]


NULLIF(COUNT(*),'%') could never be true anyway; COUNT returns an int so it can never return the varchar value '%'. Surely you want NULLIF(<aggregate function>,0) so you return NULL if the aggregate function returns 0.

I have changed and it works:
SELECT 'Accounts_Receivable__c.Payment_Frequency__c' AS Table_ColumnName,
   'Payment Frequency' AS [DATA ELEMENT],
   COUNT(*) as Total_cnt, 
   COUNT(Payment_Frequency__c) as TotalNotNull,
   COUNT(*) - COUNT(Payment_Frequency__c) AS TotalNull,
   CONCAT(100 * (COUNT(*) - COUNT(Payment_Frequency__c))/NULLIF(COUNT(*),0),'%') AS [Percent] 
FROM [EDLCleansed].[SF].[Accounts_Receivable__c]

